# Create a button and call the View in my MasterDetailPage.Detail

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In my `MasterDetailPage.Detail` I have the default code and I want to make some changes, instead have a NavigationPage I want have a ContentPage to create a button to show in all my pages but I can't call the function `<views:ItemsPage />` and `<Button Text="Hello World!"/>` at the same time.

The default code looks like this:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

And I want something like this:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage>
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <Button Text="Hello World!" />
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        SortedDictionary<int, Category> categorias = new SortedDictionary<int, Category>();
        Dictionary<int, NavigationPage> MenuPages = new Dictionary<int, NavigationPage>();

        private int posicao = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

            //MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.Browse, (NavigationPage)Detail);
        }

        public async Task NavigateFromMenu(int id)
        {
            if (!MenuPages.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                switch (id)
                {
                    case (int)MenuItemType.Browse:
                        MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(categorias[posicao].Page));
                        break;
                    case (int)MenuItemType.About:
                        MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new AboutPage()));
                        break;
                }
            }

            var newPage = MenuPages[id];

            if (newPage != null && Detail != newPage)
            {
                Detail = newPage;

                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                    await Task.Delay(100);

                IsPresented = false;
            }
        }
}
```

ItemPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="RestaurantManagerUI.Views.ItemsPage"
              Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Clicked="AddItem_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="UWP" Value="add.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HasUnevenRows="true"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" 
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="13" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ItemPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
    {
        Dictionary<int, Models.Category> _categorias;

        ItemsViewModel viewModel;

        public ItemsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
        }

        public ItemsPage(Dictionary<int, Models.Category> categorias)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _categorias = categorias;

            BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
        }

        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var item = args.SelectedItem as Models.Category;

            if (item == null)
                return;

            var selected = _categorias.GetOrAdd(item.Id, item);
        }

        async void AddItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new NewItemPage()));
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0)
                viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
        }        
    }

    public static class DictionaryGetOrAdd
    {
        public static V GetOrAdd<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> dict, K key, V value)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(key)) 
                dict.Add(key, value);

            return value;
        }
}
```

But in this last code is giving me two errors saying: "The property 'Content' is set more than once" and "Property 'Content' does not support values of type 'ItemsPage'".
How can I manage this?

Comment: `views:ItemsPage` is this a ContentPage!?

Comment: @G.hakim Yes it is. Do you want see the ItemsPage code?

Comment: No need the reason it is not working is cause you cannot embed a `ContentPage` inside another you might wanna convert it to a `ContentView` instead, Btw it does not support ContentPage inside another because `ContentPage` is not of type `ViewRenderer`

Comment: Ok I changed the ItemsPage to `ContentView` but its ocurring the same error.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not notice, but content only takes a single child put it in a `StackLayout` check my answer for a brief understanding

Answer (score 1):

`ContentPage.Content` can only have one direct child so just wrap it all in a `StackLayout`

```
<ContentPage>
        <ContentPage.Content>
         <StackLayout>
          <Button Text="Hello World!" />
            <views:ItemsPage />
         </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Ohhh yeah, oh my god  im so stupid. But in `<views: ItemsPage />` its giving me other error : A value of type 'ItemsPage' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'. It's may because my ItemsPage code now right?

Comment: Ok found the error, so I have a lot of code including this pages,so I cant change the ItemsPage to ContentView. Have some other way to declare the `<views: ItemsPage />`?

Comment: Why can't you change it to ContentView can you add more details to the question

Comment: Now I dont have any error in code but when I try to run appear me this error:`The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly. `

Comment: Add your ContentView let me take a look

Comment: So I will put the code that I think is important to see in my question.

Comment: Its a lot of code that would take me time to explain you so if you have some questions let me know.

Comment: Whatever suits you, I guess

Comment: Umm okay makes sense why you cannot convert it directly, so What you basically want is all your pages should have a button on top of them is it? As the first item?

Comment: At the button of the page, but for that I can do a grid right? (sorry for the delay)

Comment: You mean the bottom of the page is it?

Comment: Yes switched the words my bad.

Comment: Bottom of all your pages and performing the same operation on all pages or the operation changes as per the page?

Comment: Performing the same operation on all my pages, to be more specifically want to add +1 in my var posicao.

Comment: Why not subclass `ContentPage` and add this button there, and then subclass all your `ContentPages` with this new `ContentPage`

Comment: Something like this, but add buttons in place of toolbar items: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54669535/7462031

Comment: sure let me know in case if I can do anything for you

Answer (score 0):

You could create the detail page in XAML first. Then add your items page using code behind.
Here is the XAML code:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage>
        <StackLayout x:Name="ContentLayout">
            <Button Text="Hello World!"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Add items page:

```
public MyMasterDetailPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // ...

    var itemsPage = new ItemsPage();
    ContentLayout.Children.Add(itemsPage.Content);

    var viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
    ContentLayout.BindingContext = viewModel;
    itemsPage.viewModel = viewModel;
    // Add some data here
    if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0)
        viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

You need to set the current layout's binding context to the `ItemsViewModel` instead of setting it in the `ItemsPage`'s constructor.

Comment: About the BindingContext is to do it like this:
`public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
        pulbic ItemsViewModel BindingContext {get; set;}

        pulbic ItemsViewModel()
        {
                 
                 BindingContext = new ItemsViewModel()
        }
} `

Comment: No, but I have no ideia how to implement the BidingContext in my ViewModel and after doing that if it is possible to delete the ItemsPage constructor BidingContext part?

Comment: @LOLJovem Yes, you could remove that part. If you want to access the view model in your items page. Make the viewModel as a public property then set it like my code above. I've updated above.

Comment: It's only appearing the button and nothing more.

Comment: @LOLJovem If you are testing the master detail page template, the items page shows nothing because its view model's item has been initialized. You could add the code as I updated. I also created a sample for you referring to: https://github.com/landl0526/MasterDetailDemo.git